# How to append characters to a string array in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, c-strings, uppercase

I'm very new to C and I'm trying to write a program that checks if a string contains any uppercase letters, and if it does, prints them out. I'm using https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler# as my compiler (cause I don't have access to my personal computer right now) and after a test run, the results are (p.s. I know gets isn't safe):

```
main.c:16:5: warning: ‘gets’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/usr/include/stdio.h:638:14: note: declared here
main.c:(.text+0x26): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
sTrInG
Contains Uppercase!
Uppercase Letters:0

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

In this case, I expect an output something like this:

```
Contains Uppercase!
Uppercase Letters: TIG
```

My script:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    gets(str);
    int containsUpper = 0;
    char upperLetters[100] = {0};
    for (int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (islower(str[i])) {
            continue;
        } else {
            containsUpper = 1;
            upperLetters[i] = str[i]; // is this the bad line?
        }
    }
    if (containsUpper) {
        printf("Contains Uppercase!\n");
        printf("Uppercase Letters:");
        printf("%zu\n", strlen(upperLetters)); // prints 0 so upperLetters is empty..?
        for (int i=0; i < strlen(upperLetters); i++) {
            printf("%c", upperLetters[i]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Does not contain Uppercase!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you know gets is unsafe, why are you using it?  It is no more difficult to use `fgets`

Comment: This is just a learning program on a website so I don't care what I use in this case

Comment: Don't call strlen inside the loop control.There's no need to recompute the length on each iteration.

Comment: `gets` has been removed. It's undefined behavior and it can make your computer blow up if you use it, so don't.

Comment: @JL2210 It's my program, and I've explained my reasoning.

Comment: Yes, but you better not use it in production or anything other than just learning. It's incredibly trivial to replace it with `fgets(str, 100, stdin);`.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You want the loop to be:

```
int i, j=0;
for (i=0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    if (isupper((unsigned char)str[i])) {
        upperLetters[j++] = str[i];
    }
}
upperLetters[j]= '\0';
containsUpper = (j>0);
```

That is, keep a separate index of the upper letters array. And don't forget to terminate it.

A better way for the loop is:

```
int i, j, k;
for (i=0, j=0, k=strlen(str); i < k; i++) {
```

as this calls `strlen` only once.

EDIT: As user LxerLx pointed out, a character which is not a lower case letter does not have to be an upper case letter. I updated the loop for this.

Comment: The `j` and `k` outside the loop in the second example will be shadowed by the `j` and `k` inside the loop.

Comment: @JL2210, is that so? Sorry, but my old VC compiler doesn't support declaring a variable in a for statement, So `for (int i=0, j=0..` would declare a new `j` and the syntax is not `for (int i=0, int j=0...` to say that `j` is also a variable declared in the `for ` statement? Thank you!

Comment: @JL2210, does it also mean that the comma is part of a declarator list and not the sequential operator? Is there a way to distinguish between these two?

Comment: No, there's not. You can initialize them outside of the loop.

Comment: The logic of the code is not correct. The body of `for` loop should have been `if (isupper((unsigned char)str[i])) { /* do stuff */ }`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The logic is **not** correct. A character which is not a lower case letter does not have to be an upper case letter.

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
for (int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    if (islower(str[i])) {
        continue;
    } else {
        containsUpper = 1;
        upperLetters[i] = str[i]; // is this the bad line?
    }
}
```

1) is incorrect and 2) suffers from a bad style of programming.

You should append upper case letters to the character array `upperLetters`
consistently that you are not doing. Also if a character is not a lower case character it does not mean that the character is an upper case character. For example in general it can be a digit or a punctuation.

Also there is no need to call the function `strlen`. An argument of the function call should be cast to unsigned char. Otherwise it can occur that a call of the function will invoke undefined behavior.

The part of the loop with the continue statement is redundant.

The loop can look for example the following way

```
for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ ) 
{
    if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )str[i] ) )
    {
        upperLetters[j++] = str[i];
    }
}

containsUpper = upperLetters[0] != '\0';
```

If you need the number of uppercase letters in other part pf the program then the loop can look like

```
size_t n = 0;
for ( size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ ) 
{
    if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )str[i] ) )
    {
        upperLetters[n++] = str[i];
    }
}

if ( n ) 
{
    printf( "Contains Uppercase!\n" );
    printf( "Uppercase Letters: " );
    printf("%zu\n", n );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%c", upperLetters[i] );
    }
    //…
```

Or instead of the loop

```
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%c", upperLetters[i] );
    }
```

you could just write

```
printf( "%s\n", upperLetters );
```

because the array was zero-initialized and as such it contains a string.

As the compiler reported the function gets is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use the function `fgets`.

For example

```
fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin );
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't consider numbers or characters like `!?#%&` to be uppercase letters, yet your program counts them as such.  You absolutely must not use `gets`, but there is no reason in this case to replace it with `fgets` since your program is not fundamentally line-oriented.  You simply don't care about lines.  Just do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
        int c;
        char upperLetters[100] = {0};
        unsigned k = 0;

        while( ( c = getchar()) != EOF && k < sizeof upperLetters ) {
                if( isupper(c)) {
                        upperLetters[k++] = c;
                }
        }
        if (k) {
                puts("Contains Uppercase!");
                printf("Uppercase Letters: %u\n%s\n", k, upperLetters);
        } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Does not contain Uppercase!");
        }
        return k != 0;
}
```

(Note that the original program only looks at the first line of input.  Whether that is a bug or intentional is not clear. If it is intentional, add a check and break out of the loop when after the first newline character is read.)

Comment: This reads until 100 characters are read or EOF is met. On some terminals EOF is hard to send.

Comment: EOF is always hard to send, because it is not something that is sent.  And yes, this program correctly terminates after 100 characters, as opposed to the OP code which invokes undefined behavior if the first line is more than 100 characters.

Comment: If you are using a terminal which makes it difficult to close stdin to the foreground process group, then you have a QOI issue (or a user education issue) that is well outside the scope of C.

Comment: I think stopping at the newline was intended.