# Use of comma in for statement?

Tags: c

I gave an answer to [How to append characters to a string array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59648189/how-to-append-characters-to-a-string-array-in-c/59648240#59648240) but seem to have a problem in understanding the use of the comma in the initializer part of the `for` statement:

```
int i, j, k;
for (i=0, j=0, k=0;
```

In this `for` statement the comma is a sequential operator that performs three initializations.

```
int j, k;
for (int i=0, j=0, k=0;
```

In this `for` statement I got the comment *"The `j` and `k` outside the loop will be shadowed by the `j` and `k` inside the loop."*

So in the first example the comma is a sequential operator and in the second example the comma is a separator in in a declarator list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first "part" of a `for` statement can either be a declaration or an expression, but not a mix of the two.

`i=0, j=0, k=0` is an expression which uses the comma operator. It performs three assignments.

`int i=0, j=0, k=0;` is a declaration, since it starts with a type. Here the comma is not the operator, but just separates the declarators sharing the type. It declares all three variables, not just `i`, and initializes them.

If you want to declare and initialize `i`, but assign existing variables `j` and `k`, you could use parentheses to force the comma to be an operator:

```
int j, k;
for (int i = (j=0, k=0); // ...
```

(`i` is initialized from the second comma operand `k=0`, though here both will have value zero.)

Though it's probably more legible to just declare `i` immediately before the loop, using a `{}` block to appropriately limit its scope.

```
int j, k;
{
    int i=0;
    for (j=0, k=0; // ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This construct of the `for` statement creates a *lexically-scoped variable* which is visible in the loop.  The warning is correct:  it will conceal an identically-named variable outside the loop.

In this case, declare all three variables including `i` then omit the `int` keyword from the `for` statement.

Incidentally, I'm never in favor of this construction because it is extremely easy to *overlook.*  Source-code needs to be "simple and obvious," and to me this isn't.  You can easily be looking straight at a bug and fail to recognize it. *(Show of hands, please?)*

Comment: So it is a separator and not a sequential operator.

Comment: Essentially, yes:  there are three initializations being made in the first clause of the statement, and a comma is the "syntactic sugar" that separates them.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` statement has two formats, as specified by section 6.8.5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **for** ( expression<sub>opt</sub> ; expression<sub>opt</sub> ; expression<sub>opt</sub> ) statement
>
> **for** ( declaration expression<sub>opt</sub> ; expression<sub>opt</sub> ) statement

Your first snippet is an example of the first format, in which the first clause is an expression.  In this case, the comma is the comma operator.  So `i`, `j`, and `k` refer to the variables declared in the previous line.

Your second snippet is an example of the second format.  Here, the first clause is a delaration, so the comma here is a separator for declarations of variables.  So `i`, `j`, and `k` are each declared here, meaning `j` and `k` declared on the prior line are masked.

So your conclusion is correct: the comma in the first case is the comma operator, while the comma in the second case is a separator for declarators.

Comment: Is something missing in the second for? I only see one `;`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That is not a mistake.  The definition of "declaration" includes a `;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> So in the first example the comma is a sequential operator and in the
>   second example the comma is a separator in in a declarator list?

Yes.

C for loops have two forms ([6.8.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5))

```
for ( expression_opt ; expression_opt ; expression_opt ) statement
for ( declaration expression_opt ; expression_opt ) statement
```

This

```
int i, j, k;
for (i=0, j=0, k=0; expr2; expr3 ) statement
```

matches the first form => the comma is the comma operator, and

```
for (int i=0, j=0, k=0; expr2; expr3 ) statement
```

matches the second form, where

```
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
```

is the declaration  ([declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list_opt ;](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7). More concretely, `int` then forms the `declarations-specifiers` part, and `i=0, j=0, k=0` the `init-declarator-list_opt` part. Notice that the trailing `;` is part of the `declaration`. The other `;` are part of the `for`-loop construct where they separate `expression`s.).